# Why is type convertibility in C++ not transitive?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, type-traits, type-systems

Consider the following static asserts:

```
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<int const&, int const>);
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<int const, int>);
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<int, int &&>);

    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<int const&, int &&>);
```

The above three asserts pass, but the last assert fails.

This means that type convertibility in C++ is not transitive in general, which I think is very counterintuitive.

I searched the standard and the cppreference website to find any evidence that this is intended behavior, but I have not been successful so far.

Interestingly, for lvalue-references, everything is fine, because `std::is_convertible_v<int, int&>` is false. I would also expect that for rvalue-references.

I assume it has something to do with how `is_convertible` is defined. In the definition, the `To` argument appears as a return type of an imaginary function. From my understanding, a fresh value of any type is a temporary and thus convertible to an rvalue-reference. Therefor `std::is_convertible_v<T, T&&>` holds for any type `T`.

So more specifically I ask the following questions:

1. Does `is_convertible` really captures the intuition of convertibility?
2. If not, what else does it capture? Or phrased differently: is my intuition of convertibility not suitable?
3. If we understand `is_convertible` as a binary relation, shouldn't it be a preorder, i.e. transitive? Why not?

Intuitively, imho, convertiblity should mean: whenever a type `To` is required, you can also use type `From`. And this would imply transitivity.

In particular, `T` should not be convertible to `T&&`, because you cannot use `T` where `T&&` is required (you may not move from a `T` for instance, but you may move from a `T&&`).

Am I getting something seriously wrong here?

Comment: Why would you ever want to convert a reference to a constant object into a reference to a non-constant object? That breaks const-correctness. And the only way to properly cast away constantness is through the use of `const_cast`. You can however convert a reference to a constant object to another object (not reference), as in `int const&` to plain `int` (though that's really a *copy* and not a conversion).

Comment: If I remember correctly, the rule is that the compiler won't apply more than one user-defined conversion and more than two implicit conversions in attempting to match types. That's to limit the chaos that would result from more possible conversion paths.

Comment: Say you have four types `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` such that `A` can be converted to `B` and `C` and both `B` and `C` can be converted to `D`. If convertibility were transitive, there would be two ways to convert `A` to `D` with possibly different results.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude towards finding a normalization of type signatures it would be nice to use a preorder and say something like: if you have types T and U and you find a type V convertible to both T and U, you can use V as a "common type". Then you can deduce that signatures match, iff they admit the same normal form. Of course this must not break const-ness and this is why I am carefully analyzing this relation. Intuitively what "should" happen is, that you can omit top-level cv-qualifiers and rvalue-references, but nothing else, during normalization. At least this is what I would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Intuitively, imho, convertiblity should mean: whenever a type To is required, you can also use type From....

And that is what it does mean.

> ...And this would imply transitivity.

No this is not correct. Not every binary relation must be transitive. From [cppreferene](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) on implicit conversions:

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1) zero or one standard conversion sequence;
>
> 2) zero or one user-defined conversion;
>
> 3) zero or one standard conversion sequence.
>
> When considering the argument to a constructor or to a user-defined
>   conversion function, only one standard conversion sequence is allowed
>   (otherwise user-defined conversions could be effectively chained).
>   When converting from one built-in type to another built-in type, only
>   one standard conversion sequence is allowed.

The exact rules are rather involved, but consider "zero or one user-defined conversion;" so when you have user defined conversions from `Foo` to `Bar` and from `Bar` to `Baz` then this does not necessarily imply that a `Foo` converts to a `Baz`!

It is not `std::is_convertible` that has a weird notion of convertible, but the rules in C++ about what is convertible are not transitive to begin with.

Comment: It seems I got the term "standard conversion sequence" wrong, then. For me it sounded like at least standard conversions can be chained arbitrarily and the restriction is on user defined conversions, only. And from my understanding, converting between (possibly cv-qualified) reference and object types are all standard conversions.

Comment: @UniversE to be honsest I dont understand the rules in detail, so I just picked the user-defined conversion to show that it is not transitive, qed ;)

Comment: Yes, fair enough. I think this answers the main question, although the counter-example is somehow disappointing, from a mathematical point of view :-( But it seems, that also for a subset of types, which does not involve user-defined conversions, convertibility is still not transitive. But I don't want to have such a restriction anyway, so I think I just live with the fact, that transitivity does not hold.

Comment: @AndyG so what exactly breaks my initial example, then? Aren't these all standard conversions?

Comment: @AndyG yes, this is correct. But there is actually a chain leading me from `T const&` via `T const` via `T` to `T&&`, which look really odd to me. So step-by-step I can convert from `T const&` to `T&&` via this chain, but not directly in one big step. My expectation is that neither should work and the chain should somewhere break.

Answer (score 1):

> This means that type convertibility in C++ is not transitive in general, which I think is very counterintuitive.

Generally speaking, you don't want to convert `const T&` to `T&&`. This could have disastrous implications. You'd want a compiler error so that you don't accidentally `std::move` the caller's data from them (or alternatively, create an unintended copy that *looks* like no copy was made)

---

Now, what does the standard have to say about this? 
[[conv]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv)

> A *standard conversion sequence* is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order: 
>      - Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and function-to-pointer conversion.
>     - Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating-point promotion, integral conversions, floating-point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer-to-member conversions, and boolean conversions.
>     - Zero or one function pointer conversion.
>     - Zero or one qualification conversion.

So, we can implicitly convert `int const&` to `int` via [lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval) (on non-class types it removes cv qualification).

And we can also implicitly convert `int` to `int&&` via an Identity converstion (no conversion required because we can perform reference binding of a prvalue to an rvalue reference).

But we cannot implicitly convert `int const&` to `int&&` because that would require

- lvalue to rvalue conversion (Lvalue Transformation), `int const&` to `int`, followed by
- Identity conversion (reference binding), `int` to `int const&`

This is because we cannot mix an Identity conversion with other conversions in that way, according to [[over.ics.scs]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.scs#2):

> a standard conversion sequence either is the Identity conversion by itself (that is, no conversion) or consists of one to three conversions from the other four categories.

(The categories being defined by the [table in [over.ics.scs]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#tab:over.conversions))

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot. However, I am still puzzled about the error messages, clang produces. If I try to call a `void foo(int &&)` with an `int`, clang says: "no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&'", which clearly contradicts what `is_convertible_v<int, int&&>` says. This is all very confusing. Am I correct when I say, that convertibility does not only depend on the actual types, but also on the value categories? In particular: an `int` appearing as rvalue can be converted to `int&&`, but appearing as an lvalue it cannot be converted.

Comment: It can definitely be confusing, but what's probably happening is that you have an `int`, but when you pass it to the function, it's treated as `int&`. To get the implicit conversion of `int` to `int&&`, you need a prvalue `int`, a.k.a. the result of a function that returns `int`.